# Let python script still receive input while in time.sleep

Tags: python, pyautogui

What I want to achieve here is that when I press `*` the program should wait for 17 seconds before doing anything else and if I don't press anything it can continue pressing the `]` key every 11 seconds. The problem here is that if I were to press the `*` while we are in any `time.sleep` period, the press of the key will not go through.

```
   import pyautogui
   import time
   import keyboard
    
    
    
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('*'): 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
            time.sleep(17)
        else:
            time.sleep(11)
            pyautogui.press(']')
```

Comment: Use a timer instead of sleep. You can fake the sleep by creating a condition for your timer, and only doing things if the condition is False.

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of ways to accomplish this.

One of the simpler (but certainly not best) ways is to sleep in shorter increments (say 0.1 sec) to wake up periodically and poll the keyboard. You would track in a variable the system time at which point you are done "waiting" and break out of your loop at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

last_star_press = 0  # initialize variable to keep track of time of last * press

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
        last_star_press = time.time()  # update time of last * press
        time.sleep(17)
    else:
        if time.time() - last_star_press >= 11:
            pyautogui.press(']')
            last_star_press = time.time()  # update time of last key press
        time.sleep(1)  # add a small delay to reduce CPU usage
```